# How does javascript and HTML find the location of the mouse?

Tags: javascript, html

So I know how to use the onMouseMove function in HTML to find track the location of the mouse in that specific HTML tag but im curious about how js and HTML get the location themselves, cause to me getting the location of the mouse seems pretty low-level programing for like c++ or c and its way out of control for javascript.
Thanks.

Comment: Guess in what language a browser is developed?
Also, NodeJS is able to access the file system. A programming language like JavaScript just defines syntax and features, then it needs to wrapped in another "programming language" in order to be executed

Comment: They don't. Operating system does and informs browser, then browser passes info to web page.